# thread skips some iterations

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

I wrote a method that should be repeated 1000 times and the method is again another loop (like a nested loop).Since the running time was not reasonable I decided to write a thread to run it faster. Here is the method:

```
public class NewClass implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        System.out.println(i+","+j);

        /*
         * 
         * my method
         */

    }  
  }
}
```

and here is the way the main class calls it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

   NewClass myMethod = new NewClass();

   Thread thread = new Thread(myMethod);
   thread.start();
}
```

the problem is that when I run it, the thread skips the first iteration (when i=0) in the main class and then in the next iterations, it skips some iterations of inner loop (myMethod). Here is the result of println:

```
1,0
1,1
2,0
2,1
3,0
3,1
3,2
...
3,22
4,0
...
```

clearly it skips i=0 and for other iterations it cannot finish it. I'm sure the problem is not in the body of method. I run it several times without thread. It is the first time I write thread and I think the problem is in thread.

Comment: I don't think this code does what you think it does... if you want to divide up work among threads, you need to divide it and give a specific workload to each thread. This is interleaving and pretty much guaranteed that threads will interfere with each other. Also, please use the Concurrency framework. Java 5 introduced this a decade ago.

Comment: i starts at 1, how does it skip i = 0

Comment: @JRowan: You are right. It was my mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: @VTT You are not scheduling the execution of the 1000 threads you have created. And don't forget there is a main thread as well. What you are getting is because of Race condition. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition

Comment: @Prateek Thanks a lot. Based on my understanding Race condition happens when each iteration is dependent to other iterations. In my case all iterations are independent from each other.

Comment: `System.out.println(i+","+j);` << where is `i`? Something doesn't seem right that your local variable `i` is accessible from another thread.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop index for `i` starts from `1` (I'm guessing?  It's not even clear why it's in scope), so it's unsurprising that `i = 0` does not occur.  Similarly, I think you're confused about the printing order, which need not be deterministic.  It may be printing the output interspersed with output from other threads.  This is normal and expected.  I think the code is behaving correctly, it might just not be doing what you want.

I noticed you edited your code.  This doesn't really bode well for anybody being able to help you diagnose whatever unexpected behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

It just so happens that no thread calls the print function while `i` is zero. You don't compel this ordering, so it may or may not happen in that order. Either of these things can happen.

1. `i` is zero
2. A thread is created.
3. The thread prints the value of `i`.
4. `i` is incremented.

Or

1. `i` is zero
2. A thread is created.
3. `i` is incremented.
4. The thread prints the value of `i`.

Your code doesn't enforce either ordering, so it can happen either way. You only have guaranteed ordering between threads when something in your code guarantees such ordering.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I mentioned I want to distribute the iterations of calling the method over threads but it skips some iterations of the inner loop.

Comment: Well your code bears no resemblance to what you claim you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

> clearly it skips i=0 and for other iterations it cannot finish it. I'm sure the problem is not in the body of method. I run it several times without thread. It is the first time I write thread and I think the problem is in thread.

There are 2 reason why this could be happeneing.

1. You seem to be printing out `i` which is a shared between threads *without* any memory synchronization.  See the [tutorial on memory synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).  Each processor has internal cached memory so even though `i` is being modified in the main memory, the processor cache may still see the old value.
2. You also are probably seeing a race condition.  What is happening is that the first two threads (0 and 1) are started *before* either of their `run()` methods actually being called.  So when they both run and print out `1` because that is what `i`'s value is at the time.

Because of either or both of these reasons, if you run your application 10 times you should see vastly different output.

If you want `i` to be shared then you could turn it into an `AtomicInteger` and do something like:

```
final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
...
// replacement for your for loop
i.set(0);
while (true) {
    if (i.incrementAndGet() >= 1000 {
       break;
    }
    ...
}
...
// inside the thread you would print
System.out.println(i + "," + j);
```

But this mechanism does not solve the race condition.  Even better would be to pass in the `i` value to the `NewClass` constructor:

```
private int i;
public NetClass(int i) {
   this.i = i;
}
...
```

Then when you create the instances you do:

```
NewClass myMethod = new NewClass(i);
```